# Will HWE update be pushed out automatically after Aug. 7

Tags: server, updates, hardware-enablement-stack

I've been reading up on Hardware Enablement Stack ever since I got the warning a few days ago.

I was not aware of the HWE support cycle prior to this and I have various virtual machines running either 12.04.02, 12.04.03, or 12.04.04.

I update the machines using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Currently this updates and then after reboot I get the message about the end of support and instructions to update.

After Aug. 7 will my standard update routine automatically update the HWE stack for any machines that are using an EOL HWE stack?
If not, will the same instructions supplied in the message still work to update the HWE stack?

This is the message I keep talking about:

```
Your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is going out of support
on 08/07/14.  After this date security updates for critical parts (kernel
and graphics stack) of your system will no longer be available.

For more information, please see:
http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL

To upgrade to a supported (or longer supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade

OR

* Install a newer HWE version by running:
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty linux-image-generic-lts-trusty

and reboot your system.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the HWE instruction as provided by installing the trusty HWE kernel and your system will be fine - I've upgraded several 12.04 servers already using the provided instruction and it worked flawlessly.

If something ever went wrong, you can revert back to the previous kernel in the boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will likely get automatically updated (there are people still using EOL releases), but in this case, both instructions in the message will still work after August 7.